# net core 2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#

I start build App with ASP.Net on Google Cloud Platform. 
Net Core 2.0 MVC pattern

I use two Areas
and one HomeControllre in a root of Project

This is a ClinicControllel.cs class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GcpProject_AspNet.Areas.Clinic.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace GcpProject_AspNet.Areas.Clinic.Controllers
{
    [Area("Clinic")]
    [Route("admin/[controller]")]
    //[Route("[controller]")]
    //[Authorize]
    public class ClinicController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        private readonly DbConnection _connection;

        private const int _pageSize = 10;


        public ClinicController( DbConnection connection , Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<ClinicController> logger1)
        {
            _logger = logger1;
            _connection = connection;
            if (_connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                _connection.Open();
            //User.Identities.g
        }

        [Route("{page:int?}")]
        [HttpGet("index")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string userAgent, string nextPageToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
            {
                userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
            }

            using (var LookUpcommand = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {

                LookUpcommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Clinics";
                List<string> line = new List<string>();

                var reader = await LookUpcommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                ClinicModel clinicModel = new ClinicModel()
                {
                    ClinicView = new List<ClinicEntry>()
                };

                List<ClinicEntry> lst = new List<ClinicEntry>();



                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {

                    //clinicModel.ClinicView.Add(new ClinicEntry()
                    lst.Add(new ClinicEntry()
                    {
                        Clinic_Address = reader.GetString(5),
                        Clinic_Name = reader.GetString(1),
                        Phone = reader.GetString(2),
                        MobilePhone = reader.GetString(3),
                        E_Mail_Address = reader.GetString(4),
                        ClinicId = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    });
                    clinicModel.ClinicView = lst.ToArray();
                }


                _logger.LogInformation("Home page hit!");
                _connection.Close();
                return View(clinicModel);
            }
        }
        [HttpGet("Details/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Details(long?id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet("Create/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Method Index() - work correct other methods Create and Details not work correctly where Application call Method Details I see "Blank Page" in explorer
if I Press F12 in part Network message appears "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". I cannot set the breakpoint in methods Create() and Details().

File starup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Only use Console and Debug logging during development.
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
      //  app.UseExceptionHandler("Clinic/Error");
        app.UseGoogleExceptionLogging();
        // Send logs to Stackdriver Logging.
        loggerFactory.AddGoogle(GetProjectId());
    }

   // app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseGoogleTrace();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("areaAccount", "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=index}/{id}");
        routes.MapRoute("areaClinicIndex", "{area:exists}/{controller=Clinic}/{action=Index}/{id}");
        routes.MapRoute("areaClinicDetails", "{area:exists}/{controller=Clinic}/{action=Delails}/{id}");

        // for first controller   
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default",template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     // routes.MapRoute(name:"default",template: "{controller=ApplicationRole}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
}
```

What are problems ??
in Chrome http://localhost:61878/admin/Clinic/index - correct and work properly.
where I choose one of item I see http://localhost:61878/Clinic/Details/1

Comment: Does the application behave the same when you run it locally and in Google Cloud?  How do you run it in Google Cloud?  With App Engine Flex or with Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Your `routes.MapRoute` points to `{action=Delails}`, but your method is called 'Details'. Also, your 'Create Method' is not mapped to any routes...

Comment: Complete your answer, with some code if possible. Try to be as accurate as you can. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The route for Details action is wrong named. Also, there is no route for Create action. Your routes in `StartUp.cs` file should be like that:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("areaAccount", "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=index}/{id}");
    routes.MapRoute("areaClinicIndex", "{area:exists}/{controller=Clinic}/{action=Index}/{id}");
    routes.MapRoute("areaClinicDetails", "{area:exists}/{controller=Clinic}/{action=Details}/{id}");
    routes.MapRoute("areaClinicDetails", "{area:exists}/{controller=Clinic}/{action=Create}/{id}");

    // for first controller   
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    // routes.MapRoute(name:"default",template: "{controller=ApplicationRole}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
});
```

But I don't really recommend you to use routes.